# Finding similar localities based on age demographics

Tags: similarities, demography, census, age

I'm using the Australian Census data to find similar towns based on their age demographics. Some locations show a large young population, some more working age, some older with a greater number of retirees. My question is there a common approach to analysing just this age data to find similar places?

My approach so far is visual, comparing series of Tornado charts.